# Route Group Prefix : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Newbie here.  I'm trying to use a prefix for the first time.

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');



Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => ['admin']], function(){
  Route::get('/users', 'AdminUserController@index');
  Route::get('/users/create', 'AdminUserController@create');
  Route::get('/users/{id}', 'AdminUserController@store');
  Route::get('/users/profile', function());


 });
```

I keep getting this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

I've commented out all the `route` `get`  and still get the error

Comment: what do you expect `function()` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closed brace
Change

```
 Route::get('/users/profile', function());
```

To

```
 Route::get('/users/profile', function({}));});
```

Comment: }); is there just forgot to copy it here.

Comment: I can't remember if the last function needs  braces { } as well

Comment: That was it !!!

Comment: @JeffWinkler, please accept the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

`Route::group();`
Your sinppet don't have `);`

Comment: ````Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });````

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the {}:

Route::get('/users/profile', function());

Route::get('/users/profile', function(){});